# JGroups cluster nodes ports if port_range set to 0 or default value

Tags: tcp, jgroups

I would like to know if the JGroups cluster uses the next available port, even if the `port_range` is set to 0 or allowed to remain at the default value.
As per documentation, I understand, number of additional ports to be probed for membership will not be probed if `port_range` is set to 0. Will it be the same if no value is set for `port_range` and `bind_port` is set to a specific port, for JGroups TCP_PING?

Thanks,
Nivedita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `bind_port` to 7800 and `port_range` is 0 in `TCP`, then port 7800 will be taken. If already taken by a different process, an exception will be thrown and the node won't start.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Bela